# Text Extraction Using pdfbox 2.0.X jars

Tags: java, pdfbox, text-extraction

I have a Inputstream of pdf file. Now I want to extract all string content from the inputStream. I found following examples. Should I use first one or second one ? Is there any performance difference between these two ?
what is the use of PDFParser in second one?

**snippet 1 :**

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(is);

PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();

String result = stripper.getText(doc);
```

**snippet 2:**

```
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();

PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(newRandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(stream));

parser.parse();

doc = parser.getPDDocument();

String content = stripper.getText(doc);
```

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first code. The second code will work too but is outdated and not different, the parsing stuff is called within `load()`. The speed is the same. You'll get the best results by using a file as parameter, or a byte array. Using a stream will require PDFBox to do some additional buffering. Your code does not tell where `stream` comes from; if it is a `FileInputStream`, then you should use `File` instead.